# Partitioning an array about a pivot C++

Tags: c++, arrays, partition

I am trying to partition an array into two regions S1 & S2. The pivot MUST be the first element of the array. So, for example:

> 7 5 9 2 6

7 is the pivot.

I want to have the S1 region; numbers that are smaller than the pivot

S2 region; numbers that are bigger than the pivot.

Like this:

> 5 2 6 7 9

How can I implement this in C++ language?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::stable_partition`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{7,5,9,2,6};
    std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [x=v[0]](int n){return n<x;});
    for (int n : v) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
5 2 6 7 9
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0fd92ae761135398)

Comment: I think the lambda can just capture the pivot by value instead of capturing the entire vector.

Comment: @NickyC Yes that make sense ..just the first value is required